# Importing var to main.dart from another file?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

on `checkContact.dart`

```
Future<void> checkContactPermission() async {
  var status = await Permission.contacts.status;
  if (!status.isGranted) {
    PermissionStatus permissionStatus = await Permission.contacts.request();
    status = await Permission.contacts.status;
    if (status.isDenied) {
      PermissionStatus permissionStatus = await Permission.contacts.request();
    }
  }
  if (status.isGranted) {
    var contacts = await ContactsService.getContacts(withThumbnails: false);
    var list = contacts;
    list.shuffle();
    var FamilyMember = (list.first.phones?.first.value);
    await FlutterPhoneDirectCaller.callNumber('$FamilyMember');
  }
}
```

on `main.dart`

```
AwesomeDialog(
    context: context,
    dialogType: DialogType.SUCCES,
    borderSide:
    const BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 3),
    width: double.infinity,
    buttonsBorderRadius:
    const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2)),
    animType: AnimType.TOPSLIDE,
    title: 'Family member call receiver',
    desc: '$FamilyMember',   <------ here is the problem
```

I wish to get the `$FamilyMember` displayed on `main.dart` from `checkContact.dart`. The code above give me an error saying **FamilyMember isn't defined**. `print('$FamilyMember')` worked fine on `checkContact.dart` but why is that the problem occur when it is on `main.dart`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to define the `familyMember` variable outside of the `checkContactPermission` function.
Then import the `checkContact.dart` into `main.dart` file if they're in separate files.

**This will be the end code.**

On `checkContact.dart`

```
var familyMember = '';

Future<void> checkContactPermission() async {
  var status = await Permission.contacts.status;
  if (!status.isGranted) {
    PermissionStatus permissionStatus = await Permission.contacts.request();
    status = await Permission.contacts.status;
    if (status.isDenied) {
      PermissionStatus permissionStatus = await Permission.contacts.request();
    }
  }
  if (status.isGranted) {
    var contacts = await ContactsService.getContacts(withThumbnails: false);
    var list = contacts;
    list.shuffle();
    familyMember = (list.first.phones?.first.value ?? '');
    await FlutterPhoneDirectCaller.callNumber('$familyMember');
  }
}
```

On `main.dart`

```
import 'checkContact.dart';

AwesomeDialog(
    context: context,
    dialogType: DialogType.SUCCES,
    borderSide:
    const BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 3),
    width: double.infinity,
    buttonsBorderRadius:
    const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2)),
    animType: AnimType.TOPSLIDE,
    title: 'Family member call receiver',
    desc: '$familyMember',   <------ the problem will go away
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I now see the point variable outside the function. But I got a error saying that 'A value of type 'String?' can'ts be assigned to a variable of type 'String'.'

Comment: you can do null chec like this:
`familyMember = (list.first.phones?.first.value ?? '');` 
this mean you'll assign empty string to `familyMember` if the  `list.first.phones?.first.value` is null.

Comment: I'll update my answer

Comment: Thanks for the update. And all the errors (problems) have gone as you wrote on the code above. I really appreciate it. Though is there a specific reason why nothing is printed on a simulator as a text? I was expecting to get either a number or a name.

Comment: I believe this would be because the status is not granted. However you need to debug your code and simply print from both cases: granted and not granted and check the output.